# NSXMLParser parsing unwanted html tags

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I am having a wired problem with `NSXMLParser`. I am trying to parse RSS feed from [Yahoo News feed](https://in.news.yahoo.com/rss/most-popular)

But i an unable to get the exact data from the feed. Instead i am getting html tags which shows in its **Inspect Element**

I can successfully parse any other RSS feeds using the same code. Also the Yahoo RSS feed works fine in android app. I don't know what i am missing. Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code,

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:self.url];

xmlParser.delegate = self;
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if (self.isCancelled)
        return;

    self.currentElement= [elementName copy];

    if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        self.description = @"";
        self.title = @"";
        self.link = @"";
    }}
```

Here, when i log the value for `elementName` i am getting values like html, body, div, br etc.

Comment: Try This https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

Comment: thank you.. it works fine. but i would like to know if there is any problem with my code

Comment: NO . RSS feed parsing  some times unknown characters & html charters are coming . that's why i suggested above url

Comment: If you're seeing tag like `html`, `body`, etc., that means you received a HTML document, not a XML news feed. Check your URL and make sure that's correct. Or retrieve the HTML as a string and actually see what the HTML says (as it will probably give you some indication as to what the problem is).

Comment: I checked the url. As you said i retrieved it as string and i am getting the exact content in the RSS feed. there is no html tags in that string.